# How to return the individual results of a Geocoder request?

Tags: php

I have installed Geocoder following the instructions here: https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder

And then I try to run this example:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$bingApikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$curl     = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\BingMaps($curl,$bingApikey);
$result =  $geocoder->geocode('Μπουμπουλίνας 1, 155 62 Χολαργός Αττικής');
```

When I try to var_dump the $result I get an error:

```
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class Geocoder\Model\AddressCollection could not be converted to string in <b>C:\MAMP\htdocs\Wind\geocoding\geocodeCheck.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Both geocode() and reverse() methods return a collection of Address objects
>
> `first()` retrieves the first `Address`;

https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder#address--addresscollection

Try

```
$result =  $geocoder->geocode('Μπουμπουλίνας 1, 155 62 Χολαργός Αττικής')->first();
```

Based only on documentation (therefore limited), something else to try:

```
$result = $geocoder->geocode('Μπουμπουλίνας 1, 155 62 Χολαργός Αττικής');
if($result->count() > 0) {
    echo $result->first();
}
else {
   echo 'no result';
}
```

I'm also assuming you can do something like this:

```
$result = $geocoder->geocode('Μπουμπουλίνας 1, 155 62 Χολαργός Αττικής');
for($i=0; $i<$result->count(); ++$i) {
   echo $result->get($i);
}
```

This is all speculation though, as the documentation is lacking in details and I don't have this package installed to test it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get this when I try what u suggested: b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Geocoder\Exception\CollectionIsEmpty' with message 'The AddressCollection instance is empty.'

Comment: I think I hate this documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I will try all these. The documentation is indeed very poor!

Comment: Instead of echo try the print_r for above example from spenibus: `if($result->count() > 0) {
                    print_r($result->first());
                }
                else {
                    echo 'no result';
                }`

Answer (score 4):

this documentation is pretty bad.. to get data to return in a format i could use i had to use a dumper call along with a json decoder.  there are a variety of dumpers included in the source and you need to make sure that when you call them your call is case sensitive (look in the source you downloaded for the proper dumper names and the examples the author gives wont work if you just cut and paste).

here is how i got things to work:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$curl     = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();
$geocoder = new \Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps($curl);

$data = $geocoder->geocode("1600 Pennsylvania Ave Washington DC")->first();

$dumper = new \Geocoder\Dumper\GeoJson();
$jsondata = $dumper->dump($data);

$decoded = json_decode($jsondata);

print_r ($decoded->{'geometry'}->{'coordinates'});
```

the end result of the json array gives me the lat and long

```
Array
(
    [0] => -76.9818437
    [1] => 38.8791981
)
```

if you print out the whole decoded array you get all the following.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => Feature
    [geometry] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Point
            [coordinates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -76.9818437
                    [1] => 38.8791981
                )

        )

    [properties] => stdClass Object
        (
            [streetNumber] => 1600
            [streetName] => Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast
            [postalCode] => 20003
            [locality] => Washington
            [adminLevels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => District of Columbia
                            [code] => DC
                        )

                )

            [country] => United States
            [countryCode] => US
        )

    [bounds] => stdClass Object
        (
            [south] => 38.8791981
            [west] => -76.9818437
            [north] => 38.8791981
            [east] => -76.9818437
        )
)
```

hope this helps